# VS code can't load my unity project on Linux

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I got an old Unity project I am resuming work on.
On a recently installed Ubuntu 18.04, I installed Unity 2018.2.2f1 and the latest version of VS code for Linux.
I set it up following guides, getting the extension pack for Unity installed. Then attempt to open my Unity project with VS Code.

Well, it opens to a complaint that my project could not be opened properly. Something about the OmniSharp component.
I can edit code, but there seems to be a major issue with the intellisense. That hinders my workflow a bit.

Now, I am new to VS Code, so I may have missed something, but I have so far found no answers on google.

Here is the full Omnisharp log

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 8/12/2018, 1:14:41 AM
    Target: /home/grambo/personal_game_projects/KvaGram_short_games/KvaGram_short_games.sln

OmniSharp server started
    Path: /home/grambo/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.15.2/.omnisharp/1.30.1/run
    PID: 16830

﻿[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on ubuntu 18.4 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: StandAlone 15.0 - "/home/grambo/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.15.2/.omnisharp/1.30.1/omnisharp/msbuild/15.0/Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to '/home/grambo/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.15.2/.omnisharp/1.30.1/omnisharp/msbuild/15.0/Bin/MSBuild.dll'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: StandAlone 15.0 - "/home/grambo/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.15.2/.omnisharp/1.30.1/omnisharp/msbuild/15.0/Bin"
            MSBuildExtensionsPath = /home/grambo/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.15.2/.omnisharp/1.30.1/omnisharp/msbuild
            BypassFrameworkInstallChecks = true
            CscToolPath = /home/grambo/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.15.2/.omnisharp/1.30.1/omnisharp/msbuild/15.0/Bin/Roslyn
            CscToolExe = csc.exe
            MSBuildToolsPath = /home/grambo/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.15.2/.omnisharp/1.30.1/omnisharp/msbuild/15.0/Bin
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in '/home/grambo/personal_game_projects/KvaGram_short_games'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem
        Initializing in /home/grambo/personal_game_projects/KvaGram_short_games
[info]: OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem
        Auto package restore: False
[info]: OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem
        Update workspace context
[info]: OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem
        Resolving projects references
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Detecting projects in '/home/grambo/personal_game_projects/KvaGram_short_games/KvaGram_short_games.sln'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for '/home/grambo/personal_game_projects/KvaGram_short_games/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for '/home/grambo/personal_game_projects/KvaGram_short_games/Assembly-CSharp.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for '/home/grambo/personal_game_projects/KvaGram_short_games/Assembly-CSharp-Editor-firstpass.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for '/home/grambo/personal_game_projects/KvaGram_short_games/Assembly-CSharp-Editor.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in '/home/grambo/personal_game_projects/KvaGram_short_games'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpWorkspaceOptionsProvider
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location '/home/grambo/personal_game_projects/KvaGram_short_games' on host 16750.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: /home/grambo/personal_game_projects/KvaGram_short_games/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.csproj
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file '/home/grambo/personal_game_projects/KvaGram_short_games/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.csproj'.
/home/grambo/personal_game_projects/KvaGram_short_games/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.csproj
/home/grambo/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.15.2/.omnisharp/1.30.1/omnisharp/msbuild/15.0/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1140,5): Error: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error message was partially misleading.
It seems I had forgotten to install mono, and following the install instructions here: ( https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/ ), VS Code now seem to load as expected.